# How can I express this answer with 3 oscillations in terms of 2 oscillations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to express the equation $\frac{2}{9}\sin(9t) + \frac{9}{56}\cos(5t) + \frac{271}{56}\cos(9t)$ in terms of two oscillations of cosine so it'll have the form:

_cos(_t - _) + _cos(_t)

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
$$
\cos\left(y - x\right) = \sin x \sin y + \cos x \cos y
$$
with $y=9t$,
$$
\frac{2}{9} \sin\left(9t\right)+\frac{271}{56}\cos\left(9t\right) = \cos\left(9t - x\right)
$$
where
$$
x = \tan^{-1} \left(\tan x\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)  = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2 / 9}{ 271 / 56}\right) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{112}{2439}\right).
$$